# London flea market

Tags: money, london, shopping

Some years ago, early 2000s, I shopped in a flea market in London that had Roman coins, spoons, and other old artifacts. It was in an unused tube station entrance. I'm headed to London and would love to be able to go again, but I've no recollection of where or when this flea market takes place. Can anyone help me find it?

Comment: Could you give some indication of roughly where it was? Anything it was near. I doubt it was Camden Passage (below). Possibly Brick Lane on a Sunday? I seem to remember a tube stop there (Shoreditch) was closed around then.

Answer (score 2):

Quite possible it would have been [Camden Passage](http://www.camdenpassageislington.co.uk/). It's known for it's antique shops and there's a market on each Wednesday and Saturday mornings.

Comment: That's something I will definitely check out. Great to have an idea of where to go. Even if I don't find the market I encountered before, sounds like this will be an excellent substitute. Thank you for the reply!